# Functional dependencies - BCNF normalization issue

Tags: database-normalization, functional-dependencies, bcnf

I need help about a normalization issue. 
Consider a relation **R(ABC)**
with the following **functional dependencies**:

```
AB --> C
AC --> B
```

How can i modify this to **Boyce–Codd normal form** ?

If i leave it like this, it's a relation with a key attribute transitionally-dependent of a key-candidate.
I tried splitting into several relations but that way i lose information.

Answer (score 0):

> A relational schema R is in Boyce–Codd normal form if and only if for
>   every one of its dependencies X → Y, at least one of the following
>   conditions hold:
>
> - X → Y is a trivial functional dependency (Y ⊆ X)
> - X is a superkey for schema R

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form)

R has two candidate keys, AB and AC. It's clear that the second rule above applies here. So R is in BCNF.

> If i leave it like this, it's a relation with a key attribute
>   transitionally-dependent of a key-candidate. I tried splitting into
>   several relations but that way i lose information.

I'm not quite sure what you're getting at here, but I think the terminology in English includes

- prime attribute (an attribute that's part of any candidate key)
- transitively dependent (but that refers to non-prime attributes)
- candidate key (not *key-candidate*)

Answer (score 0):

This relation is in **BCNF**

> The AC and AB are super keys and the attributes B and C depend upon the super keys and so they are in BCNF

and

> There is no **Transitive dependency** in this relation

Hope,this helps